# Implement Nagios Topography to avoid over-alerting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nagios, nagiosxi

How to Implement Nagios Topography to avoid over-alerting. Also how can we improve nagios performance to get avoided from fake alerts.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use host and service dependency definition in your configs.

For example:

```
define servicedependency {
    host_name host1
    service_description NRPE Status
    dependent_service_description CPU Load
    inherits_parent 1
    execution_failure_criteria u,c,p,
    notification_failure_criteria u,c,p,
    dependency_period 24x7
    }
```

**dependent_service_description CPU Load**
These are the service that are dependent on the NRPE Status service

**notification_failure_criteria u,c,p**
When NRPE Status service is in the UNKNOWN (u), CRITICAL (c) or PENDING (p) state, the dependent service CPU Load will NOT have notifications sent out (if they were already in a state for notifications to be sent)

**execution_failure_criteria u,c,p**
When NRPE Status service is in the UNKNOWN (u), CRITICAL (c) or PENDING (p) state, the dependent service CPU Load will NOT be executed

More can be find [here](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/dependencies.html) or [here](http://sites.box293.com/nagios/guides/configurations-and-definitions/dependencies---services).

Comment: Thanks Rohlik, where do we need to these configurations server side or hosts which we are monitoring. Also in which all config files we need to do changes ?

Comment: On Nagios server side. You can just create new config file next to your others configs a put there your new servicedependency definition.

Comment: Thanks Rohlik.. for your help.

Regards,

Comment: @VishalBhosale If you are satisfied, please mark my answer as "Accepted answer". Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Rohlik. Also I was trying to avoid un-neccessary email notifications from Nagios like warning or recovery emails. How we can do that.

Comment: Look at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_gluster_storage/3/html/console_administration_guide/configuring_nagios_to_send_mail_notifications where you can find info about `host_notification_options` and `service_notification_options`, this is what are you looking for.